# How to make a paper-toolbar stay at bottom?

Tags: html, css, polymer, paper-elements

I am using Polymer paper elements. I need two toolbars for my page, one at top and other at bottom. How do I make the other one.

I have looked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/BMGMXIEXi2w) for answer. But that is a core-toolbar and I am using v1.0. Still on using `.bottom`, the toolbar remains on top.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use Flexbox for things like this. Here's an example with paper-header-panel:

```
<paper-header-panel>
  <paper-toolbar><span>Top Toolbar</span></paper-toolbar>
  <div class="layout vertical fit">
    <div class="layout flex">content</div>
    <paper-toolbar><span>Bottom Toolbar</span></paper-toolbar>
  </div>
</paper-header-panel>
```

Note that this is using iron-flex-layout & you should probably use the mixin version of layout styles instead of the classes directly as I've done here (i.e. @apply(--layout-vertical), etc) or use flexbox styles directly.

Comment: One other note - I think you could use the --paper-header-panel-x-container mixins to apply the flex styles in the first div to paper-header-panel's container div which would allow you to get rid of the first div here. The x in --paper-header-panel-x-container is the "mode" the paper-header-panel is in.

Comment: Works with enough content, but if content is less can  you make it show at the bottom of screen.

Comment: This configuration will work w/out any content. Make sure you're including iron-flex-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

The `.bottom` in the `paper-toolbar` documentation is intended to align items within the toolbar. If you want to make the toolbar itself bottom aligned, you'll need to style the `paper-toolbar` element and its container.

Styles:

```
<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  paper-toolbar.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <paper-toolbar></paper-toolbar>
  <paper-toolbar class="bottom"></paper-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: Applying extra css is breaking the rest of the elements/page for me. Can you give an working example. My paper-toolbar happens to be within a `paper-header-panel` which is absolute by default. I cannot change that property for the polymer element. Adding a div and making it relative only works for the div.